# xlw in visual studio 2015: RunInterfaceGenerator error code 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xlw

I'm trying to use xlw with Visual Studio 2015.
I downloaded xlw-5.0.2f0 and built InterfaceGenerator.exe and the xlw .dll.

Then I open an example Template in VS2015.
The XLL project seems to build, but in the end fails with the error message:

Error   MSB3073 The command ""....\VC\bin\NMAKE" /f RunInterfaceGenerator.nmake ENVIRON=Debug LIBRARY=ObjectCacheDemo vc=vc12  ALL " exited with code 3.   RunInterfaceGenerator   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   37

I suspect something needs to be done to the RunInterfaceGenerator project, which it seems is fine for Visual Studio 2013 and not above?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently, but after I recompiled all the source files in InterfaceGenerator project and use this latest InterfaceGenerator.exe to run the header files, everything would be fine.

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Also, you should specify in the command line" vc=vc14" instead of "vc12"

Comment: same experience here. seems the "Release" built InterfaceGenerator can't run.